# How to set up a listener on the selected text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am using `ActionMode.Callback` but I need to know when the text has finished being selected... for example

[image]

Answer (score 4):

in .xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

in .class:

```
textview.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new callback(textview));
...
public class callback implements Callback {

    private TextView mTextView;

    public callback(TextView text) {
        this.mTextView = text;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        int start = mTextView.getSelectionStart();
        int end = mTextView.getSelectionEnd();
        Spannable wordtoSpan = (Spannable) mTextView.getText();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.item_blue:
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start
                    , end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        singlenton.getInstance().getDatabase().createMarkText(mTextView,Color.BLUE);
            return true;

        case R.id.item_green:
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            singlenton.getInstance().getDatabase().createMarkText(mTextView,Color.GREEN);
            return true;

        case R.id.item_red:
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            singlenton.getInstance().getDatabase().createMarkText(mTextView,Color.RED);
            return true;
        case R.id.item_yellow:
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            singlenton.getInstance().getDatabase().createMarkText(mTextView,Color.YELLOW);
            return true;
        case R.id.item_erase:
            wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT), start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            singlenton.getInstance().getDatabase().createMarkText(mTextView,Color.TRANSPARENT);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.setTitle("Selecione a cor");
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_text_context, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll);
        // Remove the "cut" option
        menu.removeItem(android.R.id.cut);
        // Remove the "copy all" option
        menu.removeItem(android.R.id.copy);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is `singlenton` type?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad he's saving that value on database "Database Singleton"

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find your answer here:

[Android Text Selection Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935688/)

> The key term you're looking for here, to help you with your research,
>   is `ActionMode`, provided that your target is honeycomb or newer.
>
> The [API docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) (scroll down to "using the contextual action mode)
>   do an ok job of explaining things, once you find what you're looking
>   for, which is the biggest barrier to their use, but basically what
>   you're going to need to do is this:
>
> 1. set your `EditText` to be selectable (`android:textIsSelectable="true"` or `setTextIsSelectable(true);`
> 2. Implement the `ActionMode.Callback` interface and provide your own menu items.
>
> NOTE: as mentioned above, this only works for API level 11+.  If
>   you're targeting earlier platforms, getting the events for text
>   selection is much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you need listener without ActionMode:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.TextView

class TextViewWithObservableSelection @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : TextView(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr,
    defStyleRes
) {
    private var selectedText: String = ""
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) {
                field = value
                observer?.invoke(value)
            }
        }

    private var observer: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            field?.invoke(selectedText)
        }

    override fun onSelectionChanged(selStart: Int, selEnd: Int) {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd)
        val startIndex = minOf(selStart, selEnd)
        val endIndex = maxOf(selStart, selEnd)
        selectedText = text.toString().substring(startIndex, endIndex)
    }

    fun observeSelectedText(observer: ((String) -> Unit)?) {
        this.observer = observer
    }
}
```