# Android add listener while preserving original one

Tags: java, android, listener

I want to make something happen on text selection, which is OnLongClickListener, but inside of that I need to get selected text, which is handled by default OnLongClickListener (at least I think it is). 
Actual result, by adding just my listener, is that my method is called, I'm trying to get indices of selection bounds, but these are 0. I can also see in debugger, that no text is selected in that momment.

Code:

```
textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            int start = textView.getSelectionStart();
            int end = textView.getSelectionEnd();
            // the rest of code
        }
    }
}
```

Question: How can I preserve default listener, which will be called first and make selection and then call my function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up a listener on the selected text in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091019/how-to-set-up-a-listener-on-the-selected-text-in-textview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how listeners work.  They don't *replace* standard behavior, so there is no *default listener* to invoke to make sure something happens.

In this case, most likely your `OnLongClick` listener is simply being called before the `TextView` has actually updated its selection. In which case, you can try having your listener [delay its processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/) until after the selection is set. Look at using `Handler.postDelayed()` or `AsyncTask` for that purpose. For example:

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            new Handler().post(() -> {/*your code here*/});
        }
    }
}
```

But, that being said, `OnLongClickListener` is not the correct listener to use for text selection changes.  You need an **ActionMode Callback** instead:

[How to set up a listener on the selected text in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091019/)