# Selectable TextView with ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I have a textView that is selectable and I'm implementing an ActionMode callback. like the one below. My dilemma is, once the user has activated the selection tool, I need to be able to detect the moment they let go of either side of the pink selection tool.  Obviously, the action mode will call onPrepareActionMenu when the user is changing the selection, but I need a way to tell that the user has released or Action.UP on that tool. In other words, I need an elegant way of determining that the user has "finished" making their selection, regardless of clicking a menu item.

there doesn't seem to be a way around this.  I have a touch listener on the textview itself, but once the selection tool/ ActionMode is created I don't get touch events.

[image: example]

Someone flagged this as the same question as the question "How to set up a listener on the selected text in TextView". I already have it selectable.. the question is how to listen to the release of the selection tool once an action mode is already visible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up a listener on the selected text in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091019/how-to-set-up-a-listener-on-the-selected-text-in-textview)

Comment: not a dupe.. different issue