# how to set a listener for the selected text in TextView in java?

Tags: java, android

i want a Help just which way i follow to get a listener for the selected text in TextView,
what i want is when the user select a specified text, a button of options will appear.
i hope you help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091019/how-to-set-up-a-listener-on-the-selected-text-in-textview

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ActionListener? It will be called when user interacts or performs any action on that particular component. You can get the selected content by component.getSelectedText() or similar method. Do not write separate listeners for mouse and keyboard operations as it might interfere with one another and cause problems.