# Android select text listener to close the android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText et`. When I want to modify its text, the android soft keyboard pops up. 
The problem is that in some devices, the cut, copy and print button are all on top bar and due to the fact that the keyboard pops up while I am modifying the text in EditBox, I cant copy and paste in those devices. (Its a ListView and it is not scrollable)
The option that easily solves my problem is to close the soft keyboard once my text in `et` is selected.
I have searched a lot but I couldn't find any listener for this. Is there any solution to this issue?
I understand that I can write my own `ActionMode` but I don't want to rewrite the android's default copy/paste bar. 
I also tried to use `setOnLongClickListener()` on `et` but for some reasons it's not trigered when I select the text.

```
et.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "text is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you share screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to add some property in edittext of your xml file.

```
set your EditText to be selectable (android:textIsSelectable="true" or      
setTextIsSelectable(true);
Implement the ActionMode.Callback interface and provide your own menu items.
```

check below links,they might helps you-

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188392/text-selection-listener-in-androidapi-level-7)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935688/android-text-selection-listener)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935688/android-text-selection-listener)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I checked all of these links but they don't really solve my problem.