# Android: How to catch the global double-click events on text?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, root

Is it possible to catch the global `double-click` events on text in `Android`? If so, how to do it? Should I get `root` right first?

To be more specifically, when I `double-click` the text area in the built-in apps, the text will be selected and it will pop a menu to operate on it.

[image]

However, in other apps, such behaviour will not occur. Hence, I would like to catch the global the `double-click` events and customize the pop-menu.

Any solutions or advices will be appreciated.

---

Edit:

I would like to catch `double-click` events in other apps, not in my apps. My apps is to make such event-catching possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to set EditText  `android:textIsSelectable="true"`

And create Action mode callback

for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935688/android-text-selection-listener)

Comment: I would like to catch double-click events in other apps, not in my apps. My apps is to make such event-catching possible. I have updated my question.

Comment: i dont think you can listen other apps .

Comment: You can pass intent data to the other apps. http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html 

root == admin. so there might be possibility to do that.